# Multipile 'not' condtions in IF (XSLT)

Tags: xslt

Description:

I have a requirement where I need to check the attribute and the value of the incoming field, and if both are not NULL I populate those values in the output.

Problem :

I am getting output when even one of the values is passed (either the attribute or the actual field value). That should not be the case as I need the 'and' condition to work for "both" the input xml's.

I have two input xml:

The first:

```
<a>
  <b Ccy="INR">999.000</b>
</a>
```

The second:

```
<v>
  <z Ccy="USD">9999.000</z>
</v>
```

Code used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="fo">
  <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" 
              version="1.0" 
              method="xml" 
              indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="ccy1" 
       select="./*[local-name()='a']
                /*[local-name()='b']
                /@*[local-name()='Ccy']"/>
    <xsl:variable name="field1" 
      select="./*[local-name()='a']
               /*[local-name()='b']"/>
    <xsl:variable name="ccy2" 
      select="./*[local-name()='v']
               /*[local-name()='z']
               /@*[local-name()='Ccy']"/>
    <xsl:variable name="field2" 
      select="./*[local-name()='v']
               /*[local-name()='z']"/>
    <xsl:if test="not($ccy1 = '') 
                  and not($field1 = '') 
                  or not($ccy2 = '') 
                  and not($field2 = '')">
      <output Ccy="AAA">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$ccy1 and $field1">
            <xsl:attribute name="Ccy">
              <xsl:value-of select="$ccy1"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="$field1"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="$ccy2 and $field2">
            <xsl:attribute name="Ccy">
              <xsl:value-of select="$ccy2"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="$field2"/>
          </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
      </output>
    </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Why on earth would you use a horrible hack like `*[local-name()='a']`?

Comment: that is usual way to get a XPath isn't ?

Comment: No, it is not. Use either `a` or - if the element is in a namespace - `ns1:a` (after declaring the namespace and binding to the `ns1` prefix).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that an empty node-set is never equal to a string - not even an empty string. Therefore, in your first example, the expression `not($ccy2 = '') and not($field2 = '')"` evaluates as `true()`, regardless of whether the actual input nodes are empty or not.

Try instead:

```
<xsl:if test="string($ccy1) and string($field1) or string($ccy2) and string($field2)">
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response